# jquery UI Dialog always appears on top left corner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This question has been asked in this forum several times and I have tried every suggestion in there but nothing is working so far.

In an MVC application I have a jquery ui dialog which should appear near the link where the user clicks. So I have the following view:

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Link for popup</h2>
        <p>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Update Status", "UpdateStatus", "Home",
                        new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                UpdateTargetId = "rolesPopUp",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                OnSuccess = "openSuccess"
                            })
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>See this being updated</h2>
        <p id="rolesPopUp">Col 2</p>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 popupBase">
        <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
        <p id="successUpdate">Col 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This has been created with the sole purpose of testing the dialog. Basically I have created an MVC application in Visual Studio 2013, updated to the latest jquery and installed jquery ui. I put a datepicker to see if it works. I have the following scripts at the bottom of the page:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(function () {
        // Activate datepicker ui. It is not shown in the view file to keep the code short.
        $(".myDatePicker").datepicker();    
        $("#successUpdate").text("Waiting!"); 
        $("#rolesPopUp").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: ".popupBase", collision: "none" }
        });
    });

    // openPopup function
    function openSuccess() {
        $("#successUpdate").text("Success!");
        $("#rolesPopUp").dialog("open");            
    }

 </script>
```

No matter what I do, the dialog always appears on the upper left corner of the screen. I have tried many different positions (center of the screen/window/element, right, left, etc.), read several articles regarding this issue, added and removed the collision, tried debugging the code with firebug to see where the position changes, but since my knowledge of jquery is rather limited, I could not understand where the position is being overwritten. In fact I don't see anything in the code that suggests a change in the position by the code. I have spent 5 days on this I am not getting any way near a solution. I need some help please.

Comment: Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ddu8fygq/ Unable to replicate the issue. What is your CSS status? Are they all loading properly? Are there any that might be changing the styling? What theme are you using?

Comment: I was already trying removing all the themes one by one and your comment reinforced the idea that I am on the right track. However, the only thing I did not touch was the jquery version. I was using 3.1.0. Changing it to 1.10.2 improves the situation. I have stripped down all the themes and scripts and I am just using this: `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css, //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js, //code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js` This improves the situation but the dialog is always centered relative to the target div. I cannot place it in a specific position.

Comment: Ok. Just a point of correction, the demo uses jQuery 1.12.4 & UI 1.12.0: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

This was very simple. I was using jquery 3.1.0. Downgrading to jquery 1.10.2 worked. I have not tried any other versions of jquery. I used jquery 1.10.2, because this is what is used in the official website of jquery ui dialog http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/.

Answer (score 0):

I was using jQuery UI 1.8.7, which have below styles to dialog:

```
.css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
```

I updated it from:

```
.css({ top: 0, left: 0 })
.position($.extend({of: window }, position));
```

to:

```
//.css({ top: '170px', left: '650px' })
.position($.extend({ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }, position));
```